# Can't find the Lagrangian from L

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, classical-mechanics

I have worked out correctly that:
$L = 0.5m [h^2\Omega ^2 + a^2\dot{\theta}^2 + a^2\Omega^2sin^2\theta + 2ah\Omega\dot{\theta}cos{\theta} - 2gacos\theta]$

$\theta$ is the generalised coordinate and $a,g,h$ constants

However I'm having difficulty finding out what $a\ddot{\theta}$ is using the formula $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = 0$

since when differentiating the right bracket I get $m[a^2\Omega^2sin\theta cos\theta - ah\Omega \dot{\theta}^2sin\theta + ah\Omega\ddot{\theta}cos\theta + ga\dot{\theta}sin\theta]$ which I'm sure is wrong.

The final answer is meant to be:

$a\ddot{\theta} = a\Omega^2sin\theta cos\theta +gsin\theta$

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: "exam tomorrow" is not a permanent title, and we do not work for the short time (In 2 days, we will have to change it into "exam yesterday" :)

Comment: I agree with @JeanMarie and took the liberty of removing said text. Plus \sin and \cos render much better.

Answer (score 1):

What did you get for your partial derivatives...
$$
\frac{\partial L }{\partial{\theta}} = 0.5m[a^2\Omega^2 2\sin\theta \cos\theta + 2ah\Omega\dot\theta(-\sin\theta)+2ga\sin\theta]
$$
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}=0.5m[a^22\dot\theta+2ah\Omega\cos\theta]
$$

Next, differentiate wrt $t$.

Comment: Thank you! I see where I went wrong. When differentiating w.r.t $\theta$ I shouldn't have multiplied by $\dot{\theta}$